# Update LDAP groups and attribute atomicly

Tags: ldap

Is it possible to update the user's groups and user's attributes atomic? I basically need to update the groups and attributes of the user as a transaction. Will it possible in LDAP?

Thanks
Godwin

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on your directory server, but generally no. You are modifying two different directory objects -- the 'member' list of a group object and some other attribute(s) of a user object. These two changes could not be combined into a single modify operation.

*If* your directory server has a mechanism to update the member-of-groups attribute on a user to populate the group-member-list on a group, then you could implement a set of dependent changes on the user object (i.e. set attr1 value to 'test1', set attr2 value to 'test2', and set memberOf to 'cn=mygroup,ou=groups,o=example'). Active Directory does not permit writing to memberOf, but there may be some LDAP directory out there where it's possible.

Not a single transaction, but you've can simulate the "change X && Y" dependency within code. Update the group membership, check the return code. On success update the next group membership & check the return code. Loop through all of the group memberships being updated like this. On failure, break out and roll back the group membership changes that have already been applied. Update the next group value; check the return code, etc until you've updated all of the required group memberships. Then update the user's attributes; check the return value. On success, move on. On failure, roll back the group membership changes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My requirement is to update the membership and attributes as a transaction. Ex. I want to update the group of the user as ADMIN and update an attribute as a transaction, once ADMIN member updated and  fail while updating the attribute, then need to rollback the entire transaction. It looks its not possible since those are different directory objects.